# Heroku works locally but crashes when deployed - Flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I've made a simple Tic Tac Toe game using flask that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku.
I am following the steps outlined in [this](https://youtu.be/g7QWqKj0ch8?t=1325) video, but my app is not working. It works fine locally, but when I test it on Heroku nothing happens when I click "play X here". If I click again a few times, suddenly the X appears and disappears randomly. If I click reset game either nothing happens or I get "internal server error".

https://tictactoe--ai.herokuapp.com/

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

def tie(board):
    # Returns false if board contains None values and True if all squares on board is full
    
    for row in board:
        if None in row:
            return False
    return True

@app.route("/")
def index():

    if "board" not in session:
        session["board"] = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
        session["turn"] = "X"

    return render_template("game.html", game=session["board"], turn=session["turn"])

@app.route("/play/<int:row>/<int:col>")
def play(row, col):

    if session["turn"] == "X":
        session["board"][row][col] = "X"
        session["turn"] = "O"    
    
    else:
        session["board"][row][col] = "O"
        session["turn"] = "X"

    return redirect(url_for("index"))


@app.route("/reset", methods=["POST"])
def reset():

    if session["board"]:
        session.pop("board")
    
    return redirect(url_for("index"))


@app.context_processor
def winner():
        
    # Columns
    left = [ session["board"][0][0], session["board"][1][0], session["board"][2][0] ]
    middle = [ session["board"][0][1], session["board"][1][1], session["board"][2][1] ]
    right = [ session["board"][0][2], session["board"][1][2], session["board"][2][2] ]
    
    # Rows
    top_row = [ session["board"][0][0], session["board"][0][1], session["board"][0][2] ]
    middle_row = [ session["board"][1][0], session["board"][1][1], session["board"][1][2] ]
    bottom_row = [ session["board"][2][0], session["board"][2][1], session["board"][2][2] ]
    
    # Horizontal  = \ and /
    horizontal1 = [ session["board"][0][0], session["board"][1][1], session["board"][2][2] ]
    horizontal2 = [ session["board"][0][2], session["board"][1][1], session["board"][2][0] ]
    
    check = left, middle, right, horizontal1, horizontal2, top_row, middle_row, bottom_row

    for i in check:
        if i == ["X", "X", "X"]:
            return dict(winner="X is the winner")
        
        if i == ["O", "O", "O"]:
            return dict(winner="O is the winner")
                
    full_board = tie(session["board"])
    
    # Returns empty string if board is not full
    if not full_board:
        return dict(winner="")

    # If all squares have values and nobody has won, it is a tie
    return dict(winner="Tie!")

if __name__ == "main":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                font-size: 30px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            td > a {
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            {% for i in range(3) %}
                <tr>
                    {% for j in range(3) %}
                        <td>
                            {% if game[i][j] %}
                                {{ game[i][j] }}
                            {% else %}
                                <a href="{{ url_for('play', row=i, col=j) }}">Play {{ turn }} here.</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        
        {% if winner != 0 %}
            {{winner}}
        {% endif %}


        <form action="/reset" method="post">
            <button type="submit">Reset game</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Logs:

```
2020-09-22T06:58:44.453325+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-09-22T06:58:44.453325+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2020-09-22T06:58:44.453326+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-09-22T06:58:44.453326+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/application.py", line 65, in reset
2020-09-22T06:58:44.453327+00:00 app[web.1]:     if session["board"]:
2020-09-22T06:58:44.453327+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 377, in <lambda>
2020-09-22T06:58:44.453328+00:00 app[web.1]:     __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
2020-09-22T06:58:44.454027+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: 'board'
2020-09-22T06:58:44.460397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/reset" host=tictactoe--ai.herokuapp.com request_id=3384212e-52c7-4a7d-ab32-3ec58c133e29 fwd="178.164.96.83" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=546 protocol=https
2020-09-22T06:58:44.461261+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.211.254 - - [22/Sep/2020:06:58:44 +0000] "POST /reset HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://tictactoe--ai.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
```

It seems like the problem is KeyErrors with session["board"] and session["turn"].
When I play a few moves, sometimes it appears on the board, and sometimes not. If I refresh the page a couple of times, it appears to have stored multiple different boards, and loads a different one each time it loads the page again.
I am not able to recreate the errors when it run it locally. Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: Where is the code to run the Flask app (app.run(...) )

Comment: I have it at the end like this:
`if __name__ == "main":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()`

Answer (score 0):

Start Flask app binding to the PORT provided by Heroku

```
p = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(debug=True, port=p, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Tried that now, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Should it be `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me :/