# Error H10 when deploying React application with Flask on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, flask, heroku

So i am trying to deploy my application that has a react front-end and a flask in the back-end but i'm getting the following H10 Error when trying to deploy it on Heroku. I am not sure what I have to do to make it work.

```
2021-03-17T15:10:50.239043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=skk-stock.herokuapp.com request_id=845a47bf-a496-4159-8f07-d232ac5ec10f fwd="49.36.113.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-17T15:10:50.632559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=skk-stock.herokuapp.com request_id=e257b95b-b16c-4866-814b-5b5610b15e37 fwd="49.36.113.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

From the logs it seems that the problem is this:

`2021-03-17T15:10:32.025278+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'api'.`

The following is my directory structure:

```
|-- Procfile
|-- README.md
|-- api
|-- build
|-- node_modules
|-- package-lock.json
|-- package.json
|-- public
|-- requirements.txt
`-- src
```

My Procfile contains the following:
`web: gunicorn -w 4 api:app`

Within the 'api' folder I have an api.py wherein I have defined app:

```
from flask import Flask
from fetch_data import fetch_data, fetch_gainers, fetch_losers
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date,timedelta
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../build', static_url_path='/')

@app.route('/api/<string:ticker>', methods = ['GET'])
def api(ticker):
    return fetch_data(ticker)

@app.route('/history/<string:ticker>', methods = ['GET'])
def history(ticker):
    today = date.today()
    days = timedelta(30)
    period = today - days
    data = get_history(symbol = ticker, start = period, end = today)
    dates = []
    for day in data.index.values:
         dates.append(day.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))

    formatted_data = pd.DataFrame(zip(dates, data["Close"]), columns = ["Date", "Price"])
    return formatted_data.to_json(orient="records")

@app.route('/gainers', methods = ['GET'])
def gainers():
    return fetch_gainers()

@app.route('/losers', methods = ['GET'])
def losers():
    return fetch_losers()

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you miss setting the port, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64005571/9095551

Comment: @BeppeC yes that was one of the issues. The other one was that since my api.py was in an api folder, my Procfile had to be written like this: ```web: gunicorn -w 4 api.api:app```. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Just wanted to ask, why have you added -w 4 inside gunicorn?