# getting H10 error on heroku - using mongoengine python

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, heroku, mongoengine

I keep getting an H10 error, i tried to change my procfile but it didn't help.
it works locally on my computer but the Heroku app doesn't open.
would like to get help!
the error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

code:
app file :

```js
import flask
from flask import request, make_response, jsonify
from flask_mongoengine import  MongoEngine
from mongoengine import Document,IntField, StringField

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
database_name="API"
password=""
DB_URI=""
app.config['MONGODB_HOST']=DB_URI
db=MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()

class Book(Document):
    book_id=IntField(required=True)
    name=StringField()
    author=StringField()

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "book_id":self.book_id,
            "name":self.name,
            "author":self.author
        }

@app.route('/api/db_populate',methods=['POST'])
def db_populate():
    book1=Book(book_id=1,name="A game",author="jim")
    book2=Book(book_id=2,name="lord of the rings",author="jon")
    book1.save()
    book2.save()
    return make_response("",201)

@app.route('/api/books', methods=['GET'])
def api_books():
    books=[]
    for book in Book.objects:
        books.append(book)
    return make_response(jsonify(books),200)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return jsonify("hello")
```

procfile :

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

i have requirements and runtime files too.
thank you for any help.

Comment: you could research [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322989/first-heroku-deploy-failed-error-code-h10). It might work with other tools but could have a similar problem. Have a look onto the error logs.

Comment: Probably not setting the port, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64005571/9095551

Comment: @BeppeC didn't work for me, but thank you

Comment: @woodz I did tried the suggestions in this topic, it didn't help me. but thank you

Comment: Try to post the heroku logs, hopefully there is some extra details

Answer (score 1):

my requirements file looks like this before:

```
flask
pandas
gunicorn
```

I went over the log tail of Heroku again and notice that
many lines after the H10 error appeared, the line:"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mongoengine'" appears.
so I changed my req file to this:

```
flask
pandas
gunicorn
flask_mongoengine
```

and it worked!